# A question about the chatting system

Tags: discussion, chat

Few days ago I was helping a user solve his problem, the discussion became long in the comment section. I wanted to move it to chat, but I've never ever used chat on SE before and he's from a different timezone so we can't chat. I comment, he replies after 12h or so.

I'm not going to give him my email, nor ask him for his email. So if I leave him instructions in the chat room, will he be able to read them whenever he clicks on the link? Maybe after 2 days or so? And is it private? Like private messaging on forums?

Comment: Generally, the chat transcript lasts forever. Some low-activity rooms are deleted after a while (> 14d), but everything else will be stored eternally. That said, chat is also *fully public* and *indexed by Google*.

Comment: @FEichinger ok thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes he can. The chat transcript for the room is public and readable unless and until the room is made private or the room is deleted my a moderator or if it is autodeleted(No activity within 14d.